# Integration with product measure

Tags: measure-theory, dirac-delta, optimal-transport

So far, I have come across some definition of product measure like this one:

$$d\pi(x,y) = d\mu(x)\delta(y),$$

where $\pi$ is a product measure on the produt space $(X,Y)$, and $\mu$ is a measure on $X$.

But I don't know what $\delta$ means. Is it the delta dirac function? If yes, what the integral

$$\int_{A \times B} f(x,y) d\pi(x,y) = \int_A \int_B f(x,y) \delta(y) d \mu(x)$$

should be, provided that $A$ is a measurable set in $X$, $B$ is measurable set in $Y$ and $f$ is a  nonnegative measurable function in $X \times Y$?

Actually, I'm reading about optimal transport, and I came across it in the Villani's book "Topics in Optimal Transportation". Here is the picture:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's the Delta dustribution. What it is is written in Formula (8) !

Comment: This is the one that I don't understand.

Comment: Equation (8) is the definition of $\pi$. What do you not understand here? The idea is that the Dirac delta centered at $T(x)$ replaces the integral in $y$ by just the function with $y$ replaced by $T(x)$.